# How to define a method for return array values for wrap_parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in rails and ruby, and can't figure out way this doesn't work. I believe is more some ruby thing than rails.

If i try to do this thing:

```
class ClientesController < ApplicationController

    wrap_parameters include: parametros_aceitos
```

and have parametros_aceitos defined in ClientesController like this:

```
def parametros_aceitos
    [
        :cnpj, :razao_social, :nome_fantasia, :ie, :enderecos_attributes
    ]
end
```

i got the error:

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `parametros_aceitos' for ClientesController:Class)

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is `enderecos_attributes`?

Comment: sorry, enderecos_attributes has : (colon) which i forgot to add here in question, i edited and corrected that, Cliente model has accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos, which is the main reason i have to add wrap_parameters in controller, because the default behavior doesn't that for nested attributes